# How to cancel the dictionary to initialize ? python3.3

Tags: python, dictionary, python-3.x

It will be easier to explain my problem by explaining the code at first.

```
def initialize_function(num,instruction,emplacement1,emplacement2,current_pipeline):
    function_mapping={
    "LOAD" : LOAD(num,emplacement1,emplacement2,current_pipeline),
    "STORE" : STORE(num,emplacement1,emplacement2,current_pipeline),
    "MOVE" : MOVE_IADD(num,emplacement1,emplacement2,current_pipeline),
    "IADD" : MOVE_IADD(num,emplacement1,emplacement2,current_pipeline),
    "FADD" : FADD(num,emplacement1,emplacement2,current_pipeline)
    }
    current_pipeline=function_mapping[instruction] 
    return(current_pipeline)
```

The `initialize_function` function has an argument `instruction`. `instruction` is a string equivalent to one of the keys of the `function_mapping` dictionnary.
So when I do `current_pipeline=function_mapping[instruction]` it is supposed to execute only the value of the `instruction`. But it doesn't. Actually the `function_mapping` dictionnary is initialized before it looks for the key `instruction` so it executes one after the other all the functions LOAD,STORE,MOVE,IADD,FADD.

What can I do ?

Thank you in advance :)

MFF

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the arguments to all of your functions are the same this should work:

```
def initialize_function(num,instruction,emplacement1,emplacement2,current_pipeline):
    function_mapping={
    "LOAD" : LOAD,
    "STORE" : STORE,
    "MOVE" : MOVE_IADD,
    "IADD" : MOVE_IADD,
    "FADD" : FADD
    }
    current_pipeline=function_mapping[instruction](num,emplacement1,emplacement2,current_pipeline)
    return(current_pipeline)
```

Explanation: Your dictionary values will evaluated at runtime since you are actually calling the functions. You want to pass a reference to them instead and since functions are first class objects in python, you can do just that.